# Stop android app process and the state, page opened remains same

Tags: android, android-activity

After the location (gps location) points (latitude and longitude) can't be retrieved, how to stop all the next process (codes) after the condition ans the opened page of the app need to be same (ie, the app must not be closed).

```
if(provider!=null && !provider.equals("")){

        // Get the location from the given provider 
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 1, this);
        if(location!=null)
            onLocationChanged(location);
        else
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Location can't be retrieved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Provider Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

When the first else reached all the other process in the app need to be stopped and a alert box need to be open, but the app must not exit.

The page of the app need to be opened.